# Add 2 UILabels in UINavigationBar titleView on top of one another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I have a custom `UINavigationBar` with a 2 line label in its `titleView`:

```
        UILabel *navBarLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];  
        UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];  
        navBarLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        navBarLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
        navBarLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        navBarLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        navBarLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:124.0/255.f green:125.0/255.f blue:128.0/255.f alpha:1.0];
        navBarLabel.text = @"This\nis an example";
        [navBarLabel sizeToFit];
        item.titleView = navBarLabel;
```

But instead of making my `UILabel` with 2 lines of texts, I would like to add 2 `UILabels`, *one on top of another* to achieve the customisation of the font in each of the 'lines' separately. How is it implemented? Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a parent container `UIView` to hold your two labels, and use this parent container as your title view. In pseudo-code:

```
   UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];
   [titleView addSubview:someLabel];
   [titleView addSubview:anotherLabel];
   item.titleView = titleView;
```

...all you need to make sure is that you've set your label frames correctly so that one label is positioned above the other. How you do this will depend on whether you're using auto-layout or not, but it's pretty simple and straightforward.

Answer (score -2):

iOS allow you add two item in the bar. Try the following code.

```
  UIButton *tempButton = nil;
    UIImage  *tempButtonImage = nil;
    UIImage  *tempButtonPressedImage = nil;

    tempButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected1.png"];
    tempButtonPressedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected1.png"];
    tempButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tempButton setImage : tempButtonImage forState : UIControlStateNormal];
    [tempButton setImage : tempButtonPressedImage forState : UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [tempButton addTarget : self action : @selector(tempButtonClick:) forControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    tempButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tempButtonImage.size.width, tempButtonImage.size.height);

    UIView *tempButtonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0.0, 0.0, tempButtonImage.size.width, tempButtonImage.size.height}];
    tempButtonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tempButtonContainer addSubview:tempButton];

    UIBarButtonItem *tempToolbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tempButtonContainer];
    // custom logout button
    UIButton *temp2Button = nil;
    UIImage  *temp2ButtonImage = nil;
    UIImage  *temp2ButtonPressedImage = nil;

    temp2ButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselectedtemp2Button.png"];
    temp2ButtonPressedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedtemp2Button.png"];
    temp2Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [temp2Button setImage : temp2ButtonImage forState : UIControlStateNormal];
    [temp2Button setImage : temp2ButtonPressedImage forState : UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [temp2Button addTarget : self action : @selector(temp2ButtonClick:) forControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    temp2Button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, temp2ButtonImage.size.width, temp2ButtonImage.size.height);

    UIView *temp2ButtonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0.0, 0.0, temp2ButtonImage.size.width, temp2ButtonImage.size.height}];
    temp2ButtonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [temp2ButtonContainer addSubview:temp2Button];

    UIBarButtonItem *temp2ToolbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:temp2ButtonContainer];

    // setting right items
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tempToolbarButton, temp2ToolbarButton, nil];


    UIButton *button = nil;
    UIImage  *buttonImage = nil;
    UIImage  *buttonPressedImage = nil;

    buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"asd.png"];
    buttonPressedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-asd.png"];
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage : buttonImage forState : UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage : buttonPressedImage forState : UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button addTarget : self action : @selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

    UIView *buttonContainer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height}];
    buttonContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [buttonContainer addSubview:button];

    UIBarButtonItem *toolbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonContainer];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = toolbarButton;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need buttons, I need labels

Comment: Use label instead of Buttons.